# typeerror: n is not a function while using jquery plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typeerror

Always thanks to everyone who help his/her best to be better together.

I am a designer and a web-publisher at the same time, but a beginner-leveled newbie.

I'm trying to apply a jquery plug-in named 'sequencer' by skruf.
However, when I apply to my website, this type-error repeatedly shows up.

Here is the demo page of Skruf, the maker of this plug-in below.
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Image-Sequence-Animation-On-Scroll-Sequencer/

and these are the errors I got in the script.
Please advice me how I could get through this problem.

[Jquery screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpwOZ.png)
[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr58C.png)

P.S Is there any possibility to collide or crash if there are multiple jquery plug-ins?

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code.

Comment: can you tell me have you add jquery min in your code?

Comment: Please add more code of what you have tried. that would help better in solving your problem